# If $f$ strictly convex does $f'$ strictly increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

In an exercice on convexity, I'm near to conclude, I just need to know if strictly convex implies $f'$ strictly increasing. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f$ is differentiable. We know $f'$ is weakly increasing. Assume $f'(a)=f'(b)$ for $b>a$. Then we know $f'(x)=f'(a)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. This means $f$ is affine for $x\in[a,b]$, contradicting to strict convexity.